# Bootstrap component to group texts in boxes?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create text groups in bootstrap and assign them to boxes, something similar to how button group works?

Basically, the entire UI would have multiple boxes, with text in them. Something similar to `[this][1]`.

Comment: put them in a class and use jquery to collect it and loop it using `.each()`

Comment: But is there a css module for bootstrap that will do the UI for it?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 2.3.2 you can use wells to group pieces of text.

```
<div class="well">
    <h2>This is a well!</h2>
    <p>All this text will be grouped together in a well.</p>
<div>
```

Hope this helps.